# Why can't i see the table's in the dbo schema?

Tags: sql-server

I got a database and 19 tables in the dbo schema.
When i log in with sa login i can see every table , when i log in with other login that i created 'MDAeveryone' can't see the table's in dbo schema.

[When i login with sa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn1Kh.png)

[when i login with my own login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAjVC.png)

Comment: Have you looked into/set up user specific permissions and/or database/table specific permissions?

Comment: Because your login doesn't have access to the schema

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general DB tech support.

Comment: i logged in as sa and went to 'MDAeveryone' login premission's and i checked view all database's still won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way to resolve that issue is grant to 'MDAeveryone' sysadmin role for your server. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHYu7.png)

The right way is:
1. Add database user with login 'MDAeveryone'
2. Add permissions on database schema dbo to this user.